# Implementation of a beta-binomial test in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I have been unable to find a Python function for performing **beta-binomial test**. There is, however, a binomial test function in the [`scipy.stats.binomtest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binomtest.html#scipy.stats.binomtest) and I have used [it](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/47bb6febaa10658c72962b9615d5d5aa2513fa3a/scipy/stats/_binomtest.py#L204-L334) to get ideas for the implementation of the **beta-binomial test**. As I am not very confident of my statistical knowledge, it would be great if someone check the following code and tell whether the statistics is valid.

As you can see, instead of using directly the shape parameters `a` and `b`, they are calculated using an estimated parameter `rho` (i.e. overdispersion; estimation procedure is described [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms11101#:%7E:text=Read%20alignment%20and%20estimation%20of%20overdispersion%20%E2%80%98%CF%81%E2%80%99)). The formula for calculating `a` and `b` from `rho` comes from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/VGAM.pdf) (see page 62, under `shape1, shape2` argument).

```
def beta_binom_test(x, n=None, p=0.5, rho=0.1, alternative='two-sided'):
    
    from scipy import stats
    import numpy as np

    ## Using rho to find the shape parameters for the beta binomial
    ## rho is empirically estimated
    a = p * (1 - rho) / rho # shape parameter 1
    b = (1 - p) * (1 - rho) / rho # shape parameter 2


    if alternative == 'less':
        pval = stats.betabinom.cdf(x, n, a, b, loc=0)
        return pval

    if alternative == 'greater':
        pval = stats.betabinom.sf(x-1, n, a, b, loc=0)
        return pval


    # if alternative was neither 'less' nor 'greater', then it's 'two-sided'
    d = stats.betabinom.pmf(x, n, a, b, loc=0)
    rerr = 1 + 1e-7
    if x == p * n:
        # special case as shortcut, would also be handled by `else` below
        pval = 1.
    elif x < p * n:
        i = np.arange(np.ceil(p * n), n+1)
        y = np.sum(stats.betabinom.pmf(i, n, a, b, loc=0) <= d*rerr, axis=0)
        pval = (stats.betabinom.cdf(x, n, a, b, loc=0) +
            stats.betabinom.sf(n - y, n, a, b, loc=0))
    else:
        i = np.arange(np.floor(p*n) + 1)
        y = np.sum(stats.betabinom.pmf(i, n, a, b, loc=0) <= d*rerr, axis=0)
        pval = (stats.betabinom.cdf(y-1, n, a, b, loc=0) +
            stats.betabinom.sf(x-1, n, a, b, loc=0))

    return min(1.0, pval)
```

Answer (score 1):

Statistical numerics are a whole thing, and as a purist I would say that CodeReview does not include in its purview analysis of whether your code is correct. You need unit tests, including ones where you have chosen sample values where you've worked out - by hand, with a calculator - obviously-correct expectations. The unit tests I will show are "regression-only": they show that my suggested changes don't affect the output of your code, but don't say whether that output is correct.

If you're really not sure whether your math is correct (separable from the question of whether your code is well-written), consider instead a place like [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Generally:

- Add type hints, including for your `alternative` which - if it's not an `Enum` - should at least be a `Literal`
- Don't local-import; import at the top of the file
- Your `a`/`b` calculations can be simplified
- `n`, `a` and `b` can be put into a dictionary for kwargs parameter reuse
- Don't pass `loc=0`; that's already the default
- Rather than separate `x == p * n` and `x < p * n` checks, consider just calculating a delta and comparing that to zero as needed
- Only calculate your `y` in one place
- In the `x == p * n` case, early-return to avoid a `min` call
- I'm not sure why you gave `n` a default of `None`. I can't find a scenario where that would be valid.
- For [obscure reasons](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8913), `count_nonzero` is faster than `sum`

### Suggested

```
from numbers import Real
from typing import Literal

from scipy import stats
import numpy as np


def beta_binom_test(
    x: Real,
    n: int,
    p: Real = 0.5,
    rho: Real = 0.1,
    alternative: Literal['less', 'greater', 'two-sided'] = 'two-sided',
) -> float:
    """Using rho to find the shape parameters for the beta binomial
    rho is empirically estimated"""

    coefficient = 1/rho - 1
    a = coefficient * p
    params = {
        'n': n,
        'a': a,                # shape parameter 1
        'b': coefficient - a,  # shape parameter 2
    }

    if alternative == 'less':
        return stats.betabinom.cdf(k=x, **params)

    if alternative == 'greater':
        return stats.betabinom.sf(k=x - 1, **params)

    # if alternative was neither 'less' nor 'greater', then it's 'two-sided'
    delta = x - p*n
    if delta == 0:
        # special case as shortcut, would also be handled by `else` below
        return 1

    if delta < 0:
        i = np.arange(np.ceil(p * n), n + 1)
    else:
        i = np.arange(np.floor(p * n) + 1)

    d = stats.betabinom.pmf(k=x, **params)
    rerr = 1 + 1e-7
    y = np.count_nonzero(stats.betabinom.pmf(i, **params) <= d * rerr)

    if delta < 0:
        k_cdf = x
        k_sf = n - y
    else:
        k_cdf = y - 1
        k_sf = x - 1

    pval = (stats.betabinom.cdf(k=k_cdf, **params) +
            stats.betabinom.sf(k=k_sf, **params))

    return min(1, pval)


def test() -> None:
    def isclose(expected: Real, actual: Real) -> None:
        assert np.isclose(expected, actual, rtol=0, atol=1e-12)

    isclose(0, beta_binom_test(x=-1.3, n=10, p=0.5, rho=0.1, alternative='less'))
    isclose(0.0125026702880859, beta_binom_test(x=0.3, n=10, p=0.5, rho=0.1, alternative='less'))
    isclose(0.1000000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=0.3, n= 1, p=0.9, rho=0.2, alternative='less'))
    isclose(0.5189135546558704, beta_binom_test(x=0.6, n= 5, p=0.2, rho=0.3, alternative='less'))
    isclose(0.7289561524195800, beta_binom_test(x=0.5, n= 7, p=0.1, rho=0.4, alternative='less'))
    isclose(0.7200000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=0.2, n= 2, p=0.2, rho=0.5, alternative='less'))

    isclose(1, beta_binom_test(x=0.3, n=10, p=0.5, rho=0.4, alternative='greater'))
    isclose(0.8771254595588235, beta_binom_test(x=1.3, n=10, p=0.5, rho=0.4, alternative='greater'))
    isclose(0.2000000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=1.9, n= 1, p=0.2, rho=0.9, alternative='greater'))
    isclose(0.4810864453441296, beta_binom_test(x=1.6, n= 5, p=0.2, rho=0.3, alternative='greater'))
    isclose(0.2710438475804200, beta_binom_test(x=1.5, n= 7, p=0.1, rho=0.4, alternative='greater'))
    isclose(0.2800000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=1.2, n= 2, p=0.2, rho=0.5, alternative='greater'))

    # x < p*n
    isclose(0.0125026702880859, beta_binom_test(x=0.3, n=10, p=0.5, rho=0.1, alternative='two-sided'))
    isclose(0.1000000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=0.3, n= 1, p=0.9, rho=0.2, alternative='two-sided'))
    isclose(0.5189135546558704, beta_binom_test(x=0.6, n= 5, p=0.2, rho=0.3, alternative='two-sided'))
    isclose(0.7289561524195800, beta_binom_test(x=0.5, n= 7, p=0.1, rho=0.4, alternative='two-sided'))
    isclose(0.7200000000000000, beta_binom_test(x=0.2, n= 2, p=0.2, rho=0.5, alternative='two-sided'))

    # x == p*n
    isclose(1, beta_binom_test(x=0.8, p=0.2, n=4, rho=0.5, alternative='two-sided'))

    # x > p*n
    isclose(1, beta_binom_test(x=0.9, p=0.2, n=4, rho=0.5, alternative='two-sided'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: These are very useful points! I learned many things. Thank you! As you guessed and suggested, I am not sure of the math, so I'd better ask this on stats.stackexchange.com. I wonder how I should proceed without cross-posting. Should I remove this post or keep it and create a new post on stats.stackexchange.com and refer to this post?

Comment: Don't remove this post; it's a good one. But don't copy it verbatim to the stats site either. You can include your (refactored, potentially) code there, but more importantly you will want to shift focus to the math itself, including proper math markup notation for your formulae.

Comment: I posted the question to: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561639/does-this-python-function-correctly-implement-a-beta-binomial-test for checking the math.